# Ubuntu remaster creates too small ISOs

Tags: ubuntu, iso

I am trying to use respin which is a fork of remastersys to create a livecd of an Ubuntu installation on my virtualbox VM.

respin creates a folder called ISOLinux, dummyfs and custom.iso

The problem is that custom.iso is barely 34kb large.
When I try to boot from it on another VM it says that there is no bootable media.

Otherwise, can you suggest me some other way to package my VM into a livedvd? UCK does not work for me as well.